# Determine conditions for constants a,b,c,d so that $f \circ g$ = $g \circ f$

Tags: functions

I have a homework problem that I don't know how to get started in:

Let $f(x) = ax+b$ and $g(x) = cx+d$

Determine necessary and sufficient conditions on the constants a, b, c, and d so that $f \circ g$ = $g \circ f$

How could I approach this problem? Please nudge me in the right direction.

Comment: A start: We have $(f\circ g)(x)=a(cx+d)+b=acx+ad+b$.

Comment: don't forget about domains and codomains in your proof. It's necessary for equality of two functions.

Answer (score 3):

$f(g(x)) = acx + ad +b$ and $g(f(x)) = acx+cb+d$ for all $x$. Then $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are equal if and only if  $ad+b = cb+d$.

Comment: Thanks! I just solved it exactly the same way (i'm glad I did before seeing the answer). I thought the problem was more complicated than that, but then I just expanded and reduced.

Comment: No problem ! Cool !

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that $f \circ g$ and $ g\circ f$ are both defined and have same domain and codomain. So for equality of your functions enough to show that at every $x$ in the domain they take the same value. Which can be checked by considering
$f(g(x))=a(cx+d)x+b=c(ax+b)x+d=g(f(x))$. So just open brackets and solve for $a,b,c,d$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(g(x))=f(cx+d)=a(cx+d)+b=acx+ad+b$

$g(f(x))=g(ax+b)=c(ax+b)+d=cax+cb+d$

are equal if $ad+b=cb+d$.